# Preventing labels from lower layers showing through layers that are on top - QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, overlapping-features

I am creating a sequence of layers and layer groups - of geological units. Layers and groups higher up the sequence cover - partially or completely - lower layers or groups in the sequence, as they are made active, or visible. But I am finding that the labels for ALL active layers are showing, even through the actual visible layers - they are all polygon layers - which cover those previous layers. How can I get the labels to only show if that layer is on top? It is okay if only a part of a layer shows - as long as the label stays on that part of the layer that is visible.
I am using QGIS 3.16.1 Hannover on Windows 7.